# getting POST data django

Tags: python, django

I have implemented payment gateway using form (with post method), and they send me a payment verification after all to url I gave them. How could I receive these data and check, next send to them as verified. Should I use special view to that url or sth? Actually they only send "data" like merchant id, currency etc. there. Give me a hint at least.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the post data in `request.POST`.

Where you can access the informations as you do in a dict.

Like,

```
merchant_id = request.POST['merchant_id']
```

You can check if the request to a particular url is POST using `request.method == "POST"`.